# How to get ImageView full width when inside a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I'm placing a very wide image inside a HorizontalScrollView.
The ImageView/ScrollView height is dynamic as I've set the height to 0dp and added constraints.
 Since the ImageView's scale type is fitStart and adjustViewBounds is true - the image's width is being resized.

XML:

```
     <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mapScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/playButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mapImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.gigi.testmap.activities.quest.QuestMapPathView
                android:id="@+id/mapLinesView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mapImage"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mapImage"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/mapImage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mapImage" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I'm trying to get the ImageView width (total width, visible & invisible part). Getting the ScrollView total width will also help.
My goal is to place buttons on top of the map in positions calculated according to width & height of the rendered ImageView.

I'm loading the image using Glide:

```
final ImageView mapImage = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.mapImage);
Glide.with(mActivity).load(R.drawable.fullmap).into(mapImage);

mapImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        mapImage.getWidth(); // --> returns 0    
        mapImage.getViewTreeObserver()
             .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
 });
```

I've tried getting the width using tree view observer's global layout listener but all I got is 0. **The height is returned correctly though**.

Any help will be much appreciated,
Thank you very much.

Comment: Just change the scale type is FitXy

Comment: It doesn't help. The issue seem to be related with the fact that the image is not rendered when the global layout listener first called.

Comment: did you tried piccaso library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the image is not fully rendered once the tree view global layout listener is first called (I guess it's because the image width is pretty big) - What I did was to have a check for the image width and only if greater than 0, remove the listener and continue with my code.

```
final ImageView mapImage = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.mapImage);
        Glide.with(mActivity).load(R.drawable.fullmap).into(mapImage);
        mapImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (mapImage.getWidth() > 0) {
                    mapImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    //continue width related code here
                }
            }
        });
```

Maybe not the prefect solution and there is a small delay until the image shows up - but it is ok for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Glide.

You are setting the all views / containers `android:layout_height="0dp"`
try first to change it to any other arbitrary value or `wrap_content`.

you did not attach the code of how you are trying to get the height.

Have you tryed `mapImage.getHeight()`

Comment: Thank you for answering. My questions is about the width. Please read about ConstraintLayout in order to understand why some values are 0dp

Answer (score 0):

For Bitmap, I used to get this way

```
Glide.with(mContext())
 .asBitmap()
 .load(path)
 .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
     @Override
     public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap,
                                 Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
         int w = bitmap.getWidth();
         int h = bitmap.getHeight()

     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This solution returns the original size of the image file. I need the resized one.

Comment: try using a wrap content and use holder.mapInstaler.layout(0,0,0,0) before using Glide

Comment: The image width is wrap_content already. Not sure what you are suggesting.